# Findind 3 factors for a integer number

Tags: factoring

As a background I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve and where's from.
In Person of Interest, a TV series, one of the characters gets a phone number in the form of area code and phone number, like `555.123.4567`. After trying to call that number he realizes that it's not a phone number but if you multiply the 3 numbers (555 x 123 x 4567) you get a large integer number. This numbers when formatted correctly (adding a dot and separating the number) it becomes a set of GPS coordinates. For examples, the result of the multiplication is `1012345612567890` you can format it as `10.123456, 12.567890` and those are your coordinates.

I've been trying to recreate these to give it to a course I am preparing, but after playing with different things (getting the prime factors, etc) I have no clue how to do this, or even if this is possible.

So, give an integer similar to the one above, is there any equation/algorithm I can follow to get 3 numbers in the form of a phone number (xxx.xxx.xxxx) that when multiplied together get the orignal integer?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: There may be more than one combination in many cases. Even in the case you provide in your question, you can (for example) get the same result by dividing the first number by $3$ and multiplying the second number by $3$ (i.e., $555\div3,123\times3,4576$. So you cannot map **every** integer similar to the one above to a **unique** phone number.

Comment: Thank you, @barakmanos. I'm not trying to get a unique phone number but just one that when multiplied you can get the original integer. Any way to achieve this? Given a large integer number, can I find 3 factors that I can use to write a *simulated* phone number?

Comment: You are correct in noticing as well that for if for $a = xxx \times yyy\times zzzz$ it is related to the prime factorization.  As such, not all numbers $a$ can be written in that fashion, depending on the factors involved (in particular those with few factors such as prime numbers themselves).

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you. Is there any way I at least try?

Comment: Are you looking specifically at obtaining two $3$-digit numbers and one $4$-digit number?

Comment: @barakmanos correct. So, for the number `608270679743423` (A random location in europe), how would I find 3 numbers in the format xxx yyy zzzz that when multiplied give me back `608270679743423`?

Comment: So simply start from $100$ and increment it until you find a number which divides your input, then take the result and apply the same process on it. Then take the result and check if it's a $4$-digit number. If yes, you're done. Otherwise, continue with the inner loop, and stop if you find a good result. Otherwise, continue with the outer loop, and stop if you find a good result.

Comment: My best recommendation would be computer assisted trial and error.  You can first find the prime factorization from http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=608270679743423 (which in this case is $31\times 461861\times 42483853$) and see if you can rearrange the factors into three groups (again by trial and error by hand or with computer assistance using for/while loops).  For your random selection, it cannot be done due to the small number of factors.

Comment: Modulo? I'm trying to understand. Grab the integer number, divide it by 100, 101, 102, etc. if the rmainder is 0 that's one number. Continue until you hit another 3 digit number and then try toi find a 4 digit number?

Comment: @JMoravitz I tried this already, it's the first thing I tried, but the numbers were always either too small (2 digit or 1 digit numbers) or too big (like 42483853 in your example).

Comment: A common practice of testmakers and problem writers is to **start with the answer first** and *then* make the question.  See if you can apply that philosophy as well.  Maybe if you were looking to do gps coordinates or whatever, you can settle with a hiding place a bit further down the block or at least get them in the right area and give a smaller clue once they are there.

Comment: ok @JMoravitz thank you. I'm still going to try to go with this approach if possible.